# GUI halts synchronizing blocks, throwing 'unexpected recv fail'

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, synchronization

On **Ubuntu 16.10 x64** and GUI wallet **0.10.3.1-beta2**, I run `start-gui.sh`. My blockchain is a bit behind, so it shows synchronizing with 20992 blocks remaining.

However, this number increases instead of decreases. Eventually, I see errors mentioning `Unexpected recv fail` and `daemonBlockChainTargetHeight: possibly lost connection to daemon`.

Any way to correct this? Thanks in advance.

I should note that I had previously been running the client before the patch that kept nodes from being knocked offline for some reason (I don't recall the details surrounding this.)

My terminal output:

```
2017-03-31 01:06:53.658     7f34b00e9c80    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
2017-03-31 01:06:54.439     7f34b00e9c80    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:153   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
2017-03-31 01:06:54.880     7f34b00e9c80    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:153   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
2017-03-31 01:06:54.969     7f348ffff700    ERROR   net.http    contrib/epee/include/storages/portable_storage.h:161    portable_storage: wrong binary format - signature missmatch
2017-03-31 01:06:54.969     7f348ffff700    ERROR   wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:2081 !r. THROW EXCEPTION: error::invalid_password
2017-03-31 01:06:54.969     7f348ffff700    WARN    net.http    src/wallet/wallet_errors.h:697  /home/vagrant/slave/monero-core-ubuntu-amd64/build/monero/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:2081:N5tools5error16invalid_passwordE: invalid password
2017-03-31 01:06:54.969     7f348ffff700    ERROR   WalletAPI   src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:502   Error opening wallet: invalid password
2017-03-31 01:06:55.748     7f348ffff700    ERROR   WalletAPI   src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:551   Status_Critical - not storing wallet
2017-03-31 01:07:06.379     7f34b00e9c80    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:153   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
2017-03-31 01:07:06.462     7f348ffff700    WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:2413 Loaded wallet keys file, with public address: 43qNhT6nqg9HxH8REzMF7djYbmPZn9Fc6KVy4VsQZM8tWq1bvDN6rU3atRUQ1FiuJmNf7RPQoZHpwj7MZXeXxFye2jNe5gx
2017-03-31 01:07:13.758     7f2e079c8ec0    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
2017-03-31 01:07:13.758     7f2e079c8ec0    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:282 Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.3.1-release)
Forking to background...
2017-03-31 01:13:10.510     7f348f7fe700    WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1784 Detaching blockchain on height 1257038
2017-03-31 01:13:10.513     7f348f7fe700    WARN    wallet.wallet2  src/wallet/wallet2.cpp:1835 Detached blockchain on height 1257038, transfers detached 0, blocks detached 20993
2017-03-31 01:15:15.743     7f348f7fe700    ERROR   net.http    contrib/epee/include/net/http_client.h:441  Unexpected recv fail
2017-03-31 01:15:15.744     7f348f7fe700    ERROR   WalletAPI   src/wallet/api/wallet.cpp:721   daemonBlockChainTargetHeight: possibly lost connection to daemon
```

The daemon log:

```
[36m2017-03-31 01:59:24.843     7f9ce915bec0    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
[0mHeight: 1257058/1278061 (98.4%) on mainnet, mining at 16 H/s, net hash 54.29 MH/s, v4, up to date, 7(out)+3(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 52m 6s

[36m2017-03-31 01:59:28.452     7f892184fec0    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
[0mHeight: 1257058/1278061 (98.4%) on mainnet, mining at 18 H/s, net hash 54.29 MH/s, v4, up to date, 7(out)+5(in) connections, uptime 0d 0h 52m 17s
```

Running monerod, I receive errors related to deinitializing core and initializing p2p server:

```
2017-03-31 01:47:26.678     7f28f7322ec0    INFO    global  contrib/epee/src/mlog.cpp:145   New log categories: *:WARNING,net:FATAL,net.p2p:FATAL,net.cn:FATAL,global:INFO,verify:FATAL,stacktrace:INFO
2017-03-31 01:47:26.678     7f28f7322ec0    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:282 Monero 'Wolfram Warptangent' (v0.10.3.1-release)
2017-03-31 01:47:26.679     7f28f7322ec0    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:55    Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2017-03-31 01:47:26.679     7f28f7322ec0    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:60    Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2017-03-31 01:47:26.679     7f28f7322ec0    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:63 Initializing p2p server...
2017-03-31 01:47:27.230     7f28f7322ec0    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:89    Deinitializing core...
2017-03-31 01:47:27.235     7f28f7322ec0    ERROR   daemon  src/daemon/core.h:94    Failed to deinitialize core...
2017-03-31 01:47:27.239     7f28f7322ec0    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:77    Stopping cryptonote protocol...
2017-03-31 01:47:27.239     7f28f7322ec0    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:81    Cryptonote protocol stopped successfully
2017-03-31 01:47:27.239     7f28f7322ec0    ERROR   daemon  src/daemon/main.cpp:290 Exception in main! Failed to initialize p2p server.
```

Answer (score 2):

Such errors are typical of a timeout in the RPC connection. If you have a very slow disk, it could well be that the daemon sync processes blocks the RPC for a long time when it's adding a new set of downloaded blocks.

If this is the case, then it will stop once you're done syncing the daemon.

About the daemon error, try running it with `--log-level 2` as there is no information about why the failure happened in this log.